Next auth with base path context and keycloak
i have an app that the base path of this app is /builder
this is how the env looks like
AUTH_KEYCLOAK_ID=builder
AUTH_ACCESS_ROLES=
AUTH_KEYCLOAK_SECRET=someSecret
AUTH_KEYCLOAK_ISSUER=http://localhost:8181/realms/master
AUTH_SECRET=QNIvILDz5YvOLsK0sGYW48oWlpLqmDT551WBW2Bbay8=
#AUTH_URL=http://localhost:4200/builder/api/auth

after running the app , i get an error failed to parse
Cannot parse action at /api/auth/callback/keycloak.

i have already changed the SessionProvider basePath but does not work yet ,
please could you please help me on that
i have already changed the SessionProvider basePath but does not work yet ,
